# vim: map command with confirmation to key

Tags: vim

I've written a few macros in my .vimrc for the version control system I'm using (Perforce) (please don't suggest the perforce plugin for vim, I tried it and I don't like it). They all work fine except the revert macro, which breaks due to a confirmation prompt (which I need so I don't accidentally fat-finger my changes away). It currently looks like this:

```
map <F8> :if confirm('Revert to original?', "&Yes\n&No", 1)==1 | !p4 revert <C-R>=expand("%:p")<CR><CR><CR>:edit<CR> | endif
```

This causes bash to complain when vim tries to load the file:

```
bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Looking at the buffer bash sees, it looks like the error is that vim sends it everything after the first pipe, not just the part meant for bash. I tried a few alternatives but I can't seem to make it work. I've got it to show confirm dialog correctly when I removed the pipes and endif (using shorthand if), but then vim complains after the user gives a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of the pipe to string multiple vim commands together is not particularly well-defined, and there are numerous eccentricities.  Critically, (see [`:help :bar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3abar)) it can't be used after a command like the shell command `:!` which sees a `|` character as its argument.

You might find it easier to use the [`system()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#system%28%29) function.

E.G.

```
:echo system("p4 revert " . shellescape(expand("%:p")))
```

The [`shellescape()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#shellescape%28%29) wrapper is useful in case you have characters like spaces or quotes in the filename (or have cleverly named it `; rm -rf ~` (Don't try this at home!)).

In the interest of creating more readable/maintainable code, you may want to move your code into a function:

```
function Revert()
    if confirm('Revert to original?', "&Yes\n&No", 1)==1
        return system("p4 revert " . shellescape(expand("%:p")))
    endif
endfunction
```

which you would access by using the `:call` or `:echo` command in your macro.

Comment: There is a small bug in the solution, the command requires "p4 revert ", not "p4 ", but overall the format works. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something along these lines:

```
:map <F8> :if confirm('Revert to original?', "&Yes\n&No", 1)==1 <Bar> exe "!p4 revert" . expand("%:p") <Bar> edit <Bar> endif<CR><CR>
```

Remember that `:map` is a dumb sequence of keystrokes: what you're mapping `F8` to has to be a sequence of keystrokes that would work if typed. A `<CR>` in the middle of the `:if` statement doesn't mean ‘and press `Enter` when executing the command at this point if the condition is true’; it means ‘press `Enter` here when in the middle of typing in the `:if` command’, which obviously isn't what you want.

Building it up a piece at time, from the inside out:

1. There's a shell command you sometimes want to run.
2. That shell command needs to be inside an `:if` to do the ‘sometimes’ bit, and so have an `:endif` following it.
3. After a literal `!` everything following is passed to the shell, including `|` characters which normally signify the start of another Vim command. That's reasonable, because `|` is a perfectly good character to use in shell commands. So we need some way of containing the shell command. `:exe` can do this; it executes the supplied string as a command — and its argument, being a string, has a defined end. So the general form is `:if condition | exe "!shell command" | endif`.
4. Your shell command has an expression in it. Using `:exe` makes this easy, since you can simply concatenate the string constant parts of the command with the result of the expression. So the command becomes `:exe "!p4 revert" . expand("%:p")` — try that out on its own on a file, and check it does what you want before going any further.
5. Putting that inside the condition gives you `:if confirm('Revert to original?', "&Yes\n&No", 1)==1 | exe "!p4 revert" . expand("%:p") | edit | endif` — again try that out before defining the mapping.
6. Once you have that working, define the mapping. A literal `|` does end a mapping and signify the start of the next Vim command. In your original the mapping definition only went to the end of the condition (check it with `:map <F8>` after loading a file) and the `!p4` part was being run immediately, on the Vim file that defines the mapping! You need to change each `|` in your command into `<Bar>`, similarly to how each press of `Enter` in your command needs writing as `<CR>`. That gives you the mapping above. Try it by typing it at the command line first, then do `:map <F8>` again to check it's what you think it is. And only then try pressing `F8`.
7. If that works, put the mapping in your *.vimrc*.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can only accept one answer, but I have upvoted yours as well.